# How to accept lists of multiple elements as command line arguments?

Tags: python, linux, list, command-line, argparse

So I have a parser set up like such:

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', metavar='foo', type=ast.literal_eval, default=[], help="Foo")
```

And I need to let users enter multiple values if they so desire:

```
$ python3 foo.py -f [0x01, 0x56, 0xff] -a blah -b blah ...
```

But whenever I try more than one value in the list I get an EOF error:

```
...
File "<unknown>", line 1
[0x01,
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

What's the proper way to set up the parser to handle something like this?

Comment: did you try  `python3 foo.py -f "[0x01, 0x56, 0xff]" -a blah -b blah ..` instead?

Comment: The shell splits arguments at spaces. Quote your spaces if you don't want to treat them as separators.

Comment: @PatrickArtner better to use the proper argparse options

Comment: @Chris_Rands  the problem here is that the shell splits at spaces - I did look further than that-your dupe is better.

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see what the parser has to work with.  It's a list of strings as split up by the shell.  Your `type` function handles one string at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it in `""`:

```
python3 foo.py -f "[0x01, 0x56, 0xff]" -a blah -b blah ...
```

and then just have `foo.py` (in this case) parse it.